# Sympy Error - Cant convert expression to float

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I am trying to use SymPy to solve for the variable p by defining the function as shown.

On execution, an error " can't convert expression to float" is being raised. I have just started learning Python so I will really appreciate if someone can help me understand what's causing the error and suggest a way to fix it and solve for p.

Note- For the assigned vales of G, F and h, p= 91.65

Thanks!

```
G=0.05
F=0.32
h=231 # these values should yield p = 91.65

def get_p (G,F,h):
    p = symbols('p')
    C2 = 3.14 * h * F*F
    C1= 3.14 * G *h
    eq_p=Eq(p *(1/math.cosh(p/C1))**2 - C1* (math.tanh(p/C1))+C2==0) #raises the error "cant convert expression to float"
    sol_p=solve(eq_p)     

    return sol_p

p= get_p (G, F, h)
print(p)
```

Comment: Note that you can also create a plot: `plot(p * (1 / cosh(p / C1)) ** 2 - C1 * (tanh(p / C1)) + C2, (p, 80, 100))` (using `from sympy import plot`) which shows a zero around `87.8`. Maybe you also would like to replace `3.14` with `sympy.pi`-

Answer (score 0):

When you get an error like this and have no idea why it is happening use an interactive session to work with smaller and smaller parts of the offending line until the problem is located. In your case the issue is that math.cosh and math.tanh expect numeric arguments and you are giving it something with a SymPy symbol `p`. Fortunately, Sympy has its own hyperbolic functions. So, remove the 'math.' and then at the top use:

```
>>> from sympy import cosh, tanh
```

But another problem will become apparent: the Eq argument looks like 'expr==0' and it should be 'expr, 0' since args of `Eq` are the `L` and `R` in `L == R`: it should be in the form of `Eq(L, R)`.

Finally, check your expression with `print(eq_p.subs(p, 91.65))`...it doesn't appear to be close to zero (and a plot of the function confirms that it does not go through 0). So you have perhaps interpreted the original expression you are trying to solve incorrectly in writing it here.

Once you have the right equation then I would recommend using `nsolve(eq_p, guess)` where `guess` is an approximate value of the solution for `p`. You can import that with `from sympy import nsolve`.